# UITableCell Swipe/Slide Two or Multiple Cell

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I want to ask how could I have done this feature you can see in this image:

[image: Feature Image tutorial]

I know the `editActionsForRowAt` but I think it's not the solution for the things I need to do, so I added UISwipeGestureRecognizer and my code look like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! ConnectionTableCell
    let users = self.users[indexPath.section]
    let user = users.userInfo[indexPath.row]
    cell.userImage.image = UIImage(named: user.imageUrl)
    cell.name.text = user.name
    cell.work.text = user.work
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    cell.addGestureRecognizer(UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didSwipeForRow)))
    return cell
}
func didSwipeForRow(recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended {
        let swipeLocation = recognizer.location(in: self.tableView)
        if let swipedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: swipeLocation) {
            let textConstant = tableView.frame.width + 10
            let imageConstant = tableView.frame.width - 20
            let swipeView = UIView()
            swipeView.backgroundColor = UIColor.themeColor(color: .green)
            let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: swipedIndexPath) as! ConnectionTableCell
            let height = cell.frame.height
            let users = self.users[swipedIndexPath.section]
            let user = users.userInfo[swipedIndexPath.row]
            cell.addSubview(swipeView)
            swipeView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageConstant - 60, height: height)
            cell.name.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.tableView.rightAnchor, constant: textConstant).isActive = true
            cell.work.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.tableView.rightAnchor, constant: textConstant).isActive = true
            cell.userImage.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.tableView.rightAnchor, constant: imageConstant).isActive = true
        }
    }

}
```

But the problem is when I swipe a cell its also affecting the reused cell as you can see in this image : 
[image: swipe cell affect another cell]

Any suggestions on how to solve this issue? Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell

Comment: that library allows multiple swipe?

Comment: yes allowed multiple swipe

Comment: why dont you use tag for it?? give tag to cell and access that cell using tag

Comment: yeah also done adding tag to cell but still affecting another cell when I swipe one cell